# What is the duration of a ban?

Tags: validation, banscore, midstate

I read somewhere that a node is banned for 24 hours.

However I found the [Misbehaving()](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/239d4198645434542b01916dae5eebc7a3a7bbcc/src/main.cpp#L1685) function which makes `state->fShouldBan = true;`. But I could not find any other function that makes `state->fShouldBan = false;`. It seems that banning is forever.

If banning is forever, I guess the node also removes the misbehaving peer from its neighbor list, right? But I could not find it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'neighbor list'?

Comment: Nodes are not keeping a list of neighbors to get data from?

Comment: Bitcoin Core maintains a database of possible IP addresses of nodes to consider connecting to, called addrman. I was just confused by your usage of the term 'neighbor'.

Answer (score 2):

When `state->fShouldBan` is set, the network thread will disconnect the node, and cleanup memory. As a result, the `state` object disappears entirely. Because of that, there is no need to ever unset `fShouldBan`.

What does happen is that when the actual ban happens (not just the setting of the `fShouldBan` field), it is added to the ban table (which is IP based). Entries in this table have an expiration time. The default expiration time for newly banned nodes is controlled by the `-bantime` option and defaults to 24 hours in the future.

Comment: So as I understand the `state` object is created when a node receives a message from another node, right? And if `fShouldBan` is set to `true`, this process is cut. On the other hand, I didn't exactly get when the actual ban happens. Isn't it right after `fShouldBan=true;`?

Comment: A second remark about the IP-based banning. Is it really a good idea? A node can easily change its IP address, no?

Comment: The actual ban happens elsewhere, see the connman.Ban in SendRejectsAndCheckIfBanned in net_processing.cpp. A node can indeed easily change their IP address, but they do need to reconnect first, and IP addresses do have a non-zero cost.

Answer (score 0):

Bans last for as many seconds as `bantime` (in `bitcoin.conf`) is set to:

```
-bantime=<n> Number of seconds to keep misbehaving peers from reconnecting (default: 86400)
```

86400 seconds is 1 day.

Comment: Can you explain more about `banscore`? I was thinking that it is a threshold for deciding if a node should be banned or not, not about the time.

Comment: @ÖnderGürcan You're right! I've edited my answer.